# Display: flex breaks and fixes alignment of multiple Hugo pages

Tags: css, flexbox, hugo

If you go here:

https://mrjules.gitlab.io/hugo2

You can see that my alignment is a little off in my content of every page except my about page as my text wraps around my image (which is what I want). I can attribute this issue to removing `display: flex;`

But if I leave it in, my text does not wrap around my image and my alignment for my other pages is fine (how my site originally was), but it doesn't make my about page look nice with the text floating below the image.

I don't know if my issue is css, html or missing/not adding a class, so I've included a link to my Gitlab project.

https://gitlab.com/mrjules/hugo2

and here's my css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

html {
    background-color: #39424E;
    font-family: "nexa-light", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px
}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "nexa-light", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 1
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Nexa-Light";
    src: url("../font/nexa-light.otf")
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "nexa-light", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2ca48;
    /* opacity: 0.6 */
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    opacity: 0.8
}

li a {
    opacity: 0.9
}

p {
    display: inline;
    /* opacity: 0.8 */
}

a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1.75px solid #f2ca48;
    /* -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
    transition: .5s ease */
}

a:hover {
    color: #f2ca48;
    font-style: none
}

a:active {
    color: #ccc
}

button {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #fff
}

button:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px #111;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px #111
}

hr {
    margin: 1rem 0;
    /* background-color: transparent; */
    width: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    color: #f2ca48;
    border-width: 1px;
    opacity: 0.6
}

.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 6rem;
    width: 55%
}

.firstcharacter {
  color: #f2ca48;
  /* float: left; */
  font-family: "nexa-light", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

form {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}

article form {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

input,
button {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: #fff;
    font: 300 16px/1.4 "nexa-light", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 12px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 38%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    color: #222;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-left: 4px solid #f2ca48;
    margin: 0;
    transition: ease all .4s;
}

button {
    background: #f9415d;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    transition: ease all .4s;
}

button:hover {
    background: #222;
}

.left {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    /* margin-bottom: 1em;
    line-height: 1.8;
    letter-spacing: 2px; */
    /* opacity: 0.8; */
    /* z-index: 1; */
}

.right {
    max-width: 50%;
    /* margin-right: 50px; */
    /* max-height: 100%; */
    margin: 1rem auto;
    float: left;
    /* opacity: 1; */
    position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
    /* display: inline-block;  */
}

/* @media screen and (min-width: 528px) {
    body {
        padding: 0;
    }
    section {
        margin: 24px auto 48px auto;
    }
    #header .logo {
        margin-top: 24px;
    }
    input {
        width: 65%;
        border-left: 4px solid #f2ca48;
        margin: 0;
        transition: ease all .4s;
    }
    input:focus {
        border-left: 4px solid #222;
    }
    button {
        width: 35%;
    }
    .search-form input {
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
} */

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .wrap {
        padding: 1rem;
        width: 100%
    }
}

.tag {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0
}

.section {
    /* display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex; */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start
}

.bottom-menu {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 300;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    font-family: "nexa-light", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1em;
    opacity: 0.8
}

.footer a {
    border-bottom: none
}

#copyright {
    width: 100%;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
background-color: transparent;
position: relative;
font-weight: 300;
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
bottom: 0;
padding: 0 0 2rem;
font-family: "nexa-light", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 1rem;
line-height: 1em;
opacity: 0.8;
}

#splash {
    margin: auto 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 55%;
    overflow: hidden
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
    #splash {
        width: 90%
    }
}

#big-link {
    font-family: "nexa-light", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.5em
}

#title {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    font-family: "nexa-light", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 3rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2ca48;
    margin-bottom: 2rem
}

#content {
    margin: 4rem 0;
    line-height: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#content h1,
#content h2,
#content h3 {
    margin: 1em 0em;
    text-align: left
}

#content p {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    line-height: 1.8;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#content pre {
    line-height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #4f5b6b;
    padding: 1rem;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll
}

#content pre>code {
    border: none
}

#content code {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    background-color: #4f5b6b;
    padding: 0.2rem;
    border-radius: 2px
}

#content img {
    max-width: 50%;
    float: right;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    /* display: block; */
    /* margin: 2rem auto; */
    opacity: 1
}

.ableft {
    /* margin-bottom: 1em; */
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
    /* margin-top: -250px; */
    line-height: 1.8;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    float: left;
    /* opacity: 0.8; */
    /* z-index: 1; */
    display: inline;
}

#content blockquote {
     background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.152); 
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 21px;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 2rem 1rem 2rem 1rem;
    font-style: italic;
    border-radius: 2px
}

#content blockquote ul {
    margin-top: 1rem
}

#content blockquote li {
    list-style: disc
}

#content table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    overflow-x: auto
}

#content table th {
    font-size: 0.9rem
}

#content table td,
#content table th {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ccc
}

#content li {
    /* list-style: inside; */
    margin-left: 1rem;
    line-height: 2
}

#content li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 1rem
}

#tag {
    padding: 0.25em 0em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    opacity: 0.6
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: 400px
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100%, 1fr))
    }
}

.grid>div {
    background-color: transparent;
    /* overflow: hidden */
}

.grid>div>img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity: 1
}

.grid>div>a>img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity: 1
}

.go-left {
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start
}

.go-right {
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -ms-flex-align: end;
    align-items: flex-end
}

.go-center {
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center
}
```

Comment: Hi WinterJules, questions asking for help with non-working code require a [mcve] in the question itself. Otherwise they risk being closed.

Comment: Floats don't work in flex containers so this sounds like expected behaviour.

Comment: @TylerH. The reason why I didn't put in non-working code is that I don't know what else (if there is) could be the problem besides the one I stipulated as I figured its a problem somewhere in my css.

Comment: @WinterJules It's OK if there are multiple problems in your code. In fact, the point of requiring an MCVE here is that it requires you to isolate the problem. A good portion of the time (maybe even half), following the steps to make an MCVE allows the asker to realize what their problem is and solve it themselves.

Comment: @TylerH I normally try to figure things out on my own most of the time, hence the few posts I have on here. All I could do is describe my issue as best I can to what the problem could be or is.

Comment: @Paulie_D does that mean I would have to add my image inside the flex container in order to get what I want to work?